# Find $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(\cos{x})^2}{\sin{(x^2)}}-\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Find 
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(\cos{x})^2}{\sin{(x^2)}}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

I suppose I have to use L'Hopital's rule here but how?

**Edit:** I cannot use Taylor yet.

Comment: You can also use Taylor series with some algebraic manipulation of your function. Note that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\cos(x))^{2}}{\sin(x^{2})} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\cos(x))^{2}}{x^{2}} \cdot \frac{x^{2}}{\sin(x^{2})}$$

Comment: Do you know the answer? Is it 1?

Comment: @Mattos The limit in your comment is (infinite and) irrelevant.

Comment: no, I don't know the answer, and I cannot use taylor

Comment: Indeed, Taylor yields $$x^2(\cos x)^2-\sin(x^2)=x^2(1-x^2/2)^2-x^2+O(x^6)\sim-x^4$$ hence the limit is $$-1$$ Tools used: $$\sin x\sim x\qquad1-\cos x\sim x^2/2\qquad x-\sin x=o(x^2)$$ and nothing else

Comment: This question might turn into some kind of Exhibit A that the insistence of some curricula on a rather anecdotal tool called L'Hopital's rule is hugely misguided (except that numerous other "Exhibits A" already appeared on the site, but you get the idea). The time spent scratching one's head to turn this into a form suitable to L'H, might be better spent doing some true real analysis. Each time, the story is the same: a one-liner solution using Taylor, vs. a quite convoluted, so called "clever", solution based on L'H...

Comment: @Did It's definitely _not_ infinite when taking into account the $1/x^{2}$ term in the original problem that I neglected to write down because I was only trying to demonstrate the algebraic manipulation and wanted brevity in my response. Next time, maybe take a second to think about the context of someones response before saying it is 'irrelevant'.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, but can you please use your energy to help me understand Jacky's short and elegant answer?

Comment: @TylerDur You lost me: you are asking for explanations about an answer which is based on **the** tool you specifically excluded? So, in the end, Taylor is ok or not? Please explain.

Comment: @did. Just a question if I may. Are equivalents teached before Taylor ? Remember that I am not an educator. In France, at my time, they were given to me (as cooking recipes) much before Taylor series.

Comment: @Nixoman Is this comment supposed to answer the specific query in my last comment? We still do not know how you can at the same time exclude Taylor (your post) and ask for some details of an approach based on them (your comment on Jacky's answer).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed, they (simple equivalents) logically come before it (Taylor formula). This is why I do not understand the logic of some questions here (but, as you can see, I fail rather spectacularly to get any cogent explanation for this apparent paradox). *Tant pis, tout ceci n'est pas bien grave et certains aspects déplorables du curriculum US, dont nous voyons les effets ici, ne changent rien au fait que la formule de Taylor est un outil merveilleux...*

Comment: @Did. Thanks for your answer. The last part of it is very nice !

Comment: @Mattos *Next time, maybe take a second to*... post mathematically accurate comments. As already mentioned, yours is not.

Comment: @Nixoman Why the change of username, in the middle of the exchanges on this page? And why do you delete some of your comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{(\cos x)^2}{\sin (x^2)} = \frac{(1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4+\dots)^2}{x^2-\frac{1}{3!}x^6+\frac{1}{5!}x^{10}-\ldots}=\frac{1-x^2+\ldots}{x^2(1-\frac{1}{3!}x^4+\frac{1}{5!}x^8-\ldots)}
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{(\cos x)^2}{\sin (x^2)}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = -1.
\end{align}

Edit: Rewrite
\begin{align}
\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin(x^2)}-\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1-\sin^2 x}{\sin(x^2)}-\frac{1}{x^2}= \left(\frac{1}{\sin(x^2)}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin(x^2)}
\end{align}
then observe
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin(x^2)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x\cos x}{x\cos(x^2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\cos(x^2)} = 1. 
\end{align}
I will leave it as an exercise to show that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1}{\sin(x^2)}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use Taylor. Is there a way using L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: Thank you Jacky! But I have a problem to understand the first step after "then observe". Can you explain this a little bit more?

Answer (score 4):

If you can only use L'Hospital, rewrite $$\frac{(\cos{x})^2}{\sin{(x^2)}}-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x^2(\cos{x})^2-\sin{(x^2)}}{x^2\sin{(x^2)}}=\frac uv$$ Now, you will have a funny time since you must apply the rule four times.

I give below the successive derivatives of $v=x^2\sin{(x^2)}$
$$v'=2 x \sin \left(x^2\right)+2 x^3 \cos \left(x^2\right)$$
$$v''=2 \sin \left(x^2\right)+10 x^2 \cos \left(x^2\right)-4 x^4 \sin \left(x^2\right)$$
$$v'''=24 x \cos \left(x^2\right)-8 x^5 \cos \left(x^2\right)-36 x^3 \sin \left(x^2\right)$$
$$v''''=-156 x^2 \sin \left(x^2\right)+\color{red}{24 \cos \left(x^2\right)}+16 x^6 \sin
   \left(x^2\right)-112 x^4 \cos \left(x^2\right)$$ where, for first time, you see a term which is not going to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it's simpler if you compute 
$$ \lim_{x->0}\frac{x^2(\cos{x})^2 - \sin{x^2}}{x^2\sin{x^2}} $$

Note that you can substitute $x^2$ for $\sin{x^2}$ as x tends to zero and $t$ for $x^2$, the above limit equals to 
$$\lim_{t->0} \frac{t(\cos{\sqrt{t}})^2-\sin{t}}{t^2}$$

Taylor's theorem is indeed convenient, but you can also use L'Hopital's rule twice, which involves some computation. If we are to use L'Hopital's rule, substituting t for $x^2$ reduces loads of work, I suppose.

The answer, by the way, is -1.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your life by noting that

$$\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}=x\frac{x}{\sin x}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\to 0$$

So $$\frac{(\cos x)^2}{\sin (x^2)}-\frac{(\cos x)^2}{x^2}\to 0$$

and the limit becomes 
$$\frac{(\cos x)^2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
 which is much easier, even if you use the hospital rule.